# How to filter Dates and JSon Data using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting two values from DatePicker (End,Start). I'd like to filter data and get data between those two values.

But i couldn't get it to work the write way.

To focus on the problem, Let's consider the both value (Start Date and End Date)

```
// Here I want to 
//var myDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(2013, 1, 28);
var endDate = new Date(2013, 1, 30);
```

The data I have is like :

```
var filter_data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.98115508098644, 40.755304404503995]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 0,
        "properties": {
            "Date": "01/20/2013 08:58:03 PM",
            "lat": 40.755304404503995,
            "lon": -73.98115508098644,
            "Address": "33 WEST 44 STREET"
        }
    },, {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.968253883967947, 40.765050901514641]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 1,
        "properties": {
            "Date": "01/29/2013 02:53:11 PM",
            "lat": 40.765050901514641,
            "lon": -73.968253883967947,
            "Address": "564 PARK AVENUE"
        }
    }, 
                ]
};
```

To filter the data, I used two different approaches, but none of these approaches work.

```
var filteredData_2 = filter_data.where( ( n, i ) => n.properties.Date <startDate && n.properties.endDate ) ;

 var filteredData = filter_data.filter(function(a){return a.properties.Date >startDate && a.properties.Date <endDate;});


console.log(filteredData_2)

console.log(filteredData)
```

Here is the like to JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnvrw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert your string into a JavaScript Date() object:

```
function parseDate(dateString){
     var dateParts = dateString.split(' ');
     var dateArr = dateParts[0].split('/');
     var timeArr = dateParts[1].split(':');
     if(dateParts[2] === 'PM'){
         timeArr[0] += 12;   
     }
     return new Date(dateArr[0], dateArr[1], dateArr[2], timeArr[0], timeArr[1], timeArr[2]);
}
```

Then you need to actually filter on the `features` array:

```
 var filteredData = filter_data.features.filter(function(a){return parseDate(a.properties.Date) > startDate && parseDate(a.properties.Date) < endDate;});
```

EDIT: moonwave99 shows that you can safely create a Date() by passing the string as an argument, reducing the solution to:

```
 var filteredData = filter_data.features.filter(function(a){return new Date(a.properties.Date) > startDate && new Date(a.properties.Date) < endDate;});
```

Updated fiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/emVJV/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/emVJV/2)

Fiddle for simplified answer:

[http://jsfiddle.net/2rXBN/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/2rXBN/2)

Comment: It should be  "> startDate" and not " < startDate". Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `Date` objects [`startDate`, `endDate`] with plain strings.

Wrap `a.properties.Date` into a proper `Date` object:

```
... function(a){
  aDate = new Date(a.properties.Date);
  aDate < startDate && aDate < endDate;
})
```